# How to validate location path in Firebase Rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I would like to validate `$username` length to be longer than 5 character and shorter than 24 character

```
{
    "rules": {
        "user": {
            "$username": {
                ".write": "auth != null",
                "uid": {},
                "created": {},
                "lastlogin": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(if it's possible) How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can validate the $username with a regex

```js
{
    "rules": {
        "user": {
            "$username": {
                ".write": "auth != null",
                ".validate": "$username.matches(/^.{6,23}$/)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "user": {
            "$username": {
                ".write": "auth != null",
                ".validate":"newData.hasChildren(['validate_username'])",
                "validate_username":{
                    ".validate":"
                        newData.val() == $username
                        && newData.val().length > 5
                        && newData.val().length < 24
                    "
                },
                "uid": {},
                "created": {},
                "lastlogin": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```